# Closure goog.require. Compile error

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

I use Google closure library and compiler in my project.

I get strange error on next string:

```
if (!properties.name) {
    throw {message: 'Widget name expected'};
}
properties.name = properties.name.toLowerCase();
goog.require('DOMless.' + properties.parent);

goog.require('DOMless.' + properties.parent);
// ERROR - Syntax error in JS String literal
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Lines before error are added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`goog.require` is a specific instruction for the Closure compiler, which will be removed from the script.

As it's not interpreted by the JavaScript engine, I think you simply can't use something's else than a string as argument.

Comment: Thank you. It's sad. I will search another way.